# how to resolve error : Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I got two object has some white space didn't match.
when I'm using two replace function in the for..of  it reports error.
if I use just one replace it works .
but object  mismatch

**my code is here :**

```
 const jsonText = await tableFlyoutPanel.json.textJsonContent();
const rowContent = await alarmTable.rowContentWithHeaders(1, true);
for (const header of Object.keys(jsonText)) {
  const text = jsonText[header].replace(/s+/gm, '');
  const content = rowContent[header].replace(/s+/gm, '');
  expect(text).toStrictEqual(expect.stringContaining(content));
}
```

it returns error in "Content" .
ERROR CODE: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined.

```
   console.log(rowContent);.
 {
  Time: '2021-07-10 03:42:01.000 (1 month ago)',
  'Node name': 'sapc17',
  'Node type': '-',
  Severity: 'Major',
  'Alarm name': 'Performance Management Threshold Crossed or Reached',
  'Faulty resource': 'ManagedElement=1,SystemFunctions=1,Pm=1,PmJob=memoryLoadThresholdJob,MeasurementReader=memoryLoad_mr:OSProcessingUnit=PL-3',
  Description: 'Observed value: 80; Threshold level: 80; MeasurementType: ManagedElement=1,SystemFunctions=1,Pm=1,PmGroup=OSProcessingUnit,MeasurementType=Mem.PercentUsed; Threshold Direction: INCREASING; MO instance: OSProcessingUnit=PL-3'
}
```

expecting value is here:
console.log(jsonText);.

```
 {
  'Node name': 'sapc17',
  'Alarm name': 'Performance Management Threshold Crossed or Reached',
  Severity: 'Major',
  'Faulty resource': 'ManagedElement=1,SystemFunctions=1,Pm=1,PmJob    =memoryLoadThresholdJob,MeasurementReader=memoryLoad_mr:OSProcessingUnit    =PL-3',
  'Fault id': '628',
  Description: 'Observed value: 80; Threshold level: 80; MeasurementType:     ManagedElement=1,SystemFunctions=1,Pm=1,PmGroup=OSProcessingUnit    ,MeasurementType=Mem.PercentUsed; Threshold Direction: INCREASING; MO     instance: OSProcessingUnit=PL-3',
  Time: '2021-07-10 03:42:01.000 (1 month ago)',
  'Event type': 'QUALITYOFSERVICEALARM',
  'Node type': '-',
  'Probable cause': '-',
  Code: '-',
  Action: '-'
}
```

Comment: What is the runtime value of `rowContent`?  What is the runtime value of `header`?  Why do you expect `rowContent` to have a property by that name?

Comment: runtime value of rowContent= "{
      Time: '2021-07-10 03:42:01.000 (1 month ago)',
      'Node name': 'sapc17'
    }"     .     header is key of object    .   runtime value of rowContent[header]:"sapc17".    "2021-07-10 03:42:01.000 (1 month ago)"         .   this way it out put key value of object

Comment: It sounds like you’re doing more assuming than debugging.  How about jsonText?  When you log it to the console, what is its value?  The error here is obvious.  You’re using one object to get keys and using those keys to read another object.  Clearly the objects aren’t the same structure.

Comment: situation is rowContent is value we see in home page , jsonText is after click detail button opened new flyout  value is same , layout is different.                              console.log(jsonText):"{'Node name': 'sapc17',
      'Alarm name': 'Performance Management Threshold Crossed or Reached',}" .                     console.log(jsonText[header]): "sapc17", "Performance Management Threshold Crossed or Reached"

Comment: Ok, now that you've examined the values of your objects... *look at them*.  `jsonText` has three properties.  `rowContent` has two properties.  You're trying to use the property keys from `jsonText` to read the values of `rowContent`.  Clearly that third property is `undefined` since `rowContent` has only two properties.  It's not clear what this code is trying to do or why, but your assumption that both objects will have the same properties is a false assumption.

Comment: no  man I'm not assuming, it returns some undefined value, I've never meet before,    anyway thanks for your advises~~

Comment: yes, you are right,  [rowContent] has 12 properties, [jsonText] has 8 properties, but this 8 properties is same in both side,            the point I don't understand is why the replace function get undefined value.                   I wanna post all properties in here but characters up to limit

Comment: *"[rowContent] has 12 properties, [jsonText] has 8 properties"* - Not according to the comments you wrote earlier.  It again sounds like you're not debugging, you're just assuming.  *"I wanna post all properties in here but characters up to limit"* - The question above has no character limit, and relevant information about the problem should go in the question.  Take some time and update the question to provide complete and meaningful information about the problem.  Not vague descriptions of what you're trying to build, not assumptions of how it should work, but specific observed data.

Comment: sure, I've updated  all properties in question area,     that's my bad, Thanks~~

Comment: Once again… Look at your objects.  jsonText contains properties that rowContent does not.  When you try to read the property “Fault id” on rowContent, what value do you expect that property to have and why?  The same is true of all the other properties that exist on jsonText but don’t exist on rowContent.  Any value that isn’t defined is…. *undefined*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting property keys from `jsonText`:

```
for (const header of Object.keys(jsonText)) {
```

And trying to use them to read properties from `rowContent`:

```
const content = rowContent[header].replace(/s+/gm, '');
```

But what properties do those objects have?  Well, `jsonText` has these properties:

```
{
   "Node name":"sapc17",
   "Alarm name":"Performance Management Threshold Crossed or Reached",
   "Severity":"Major",
   "Faulty resource":"ManagedElement=1,SystemFunctions=1,Pm=1,PmJob =memoryLoadThresholdJob,MeasurementReader=memoryLoad_mr:OSProcessingUnit =PL-3",
   "Fault id":"628",
   "Description":"Observed value: 80; Threshold level: 80; MeasurementType: ManagedElement=1,SystemFunctions=1,Pm=1,PmGroup=OSProcessingUnit ,MeasurementType=Mem.PercentUsed; Threshold Direction: INCREASING; MO instance: OSProcessingUnit=PL-3",
   "Time":"2021-07-10 03:42:01.000 (1 month ago)",
   "Event type":"QUALITYOFSERVICEALARM",
   "Node type":"-",
   "Probable cause":"-",
   "Code":"-",
   "Action":"-"
}
```

And `rowContent` has these properties:

```
{
  Time: '2021-07-10 03:42:01.000 (1 month ago)',
  'Node name': 'sapc17',
  'Node type': '-',
  Severity: 'Major',
  'Alarm name': 'Performance Management Threshold Crossed or Reached',
  'Faulty resource': 'ManagedElement=1,SystemFunctions=1,Pm=1,PmJob=memoryLoadThresholdJob,MeasurementReader=memoryLoad_mr:OSProcessingUnit=PL-3',
  Description: 'Observed value: 80; Threshold level: 80; MeasurementType: ManagedElement=1,SystemFunctions=1,Pm=1,PmGroup=OSProcessingUnit,MeasurementType=Mem.PercentUsed; Threshold Direction: INCREASING; MO instance: OSProcessingUnit=PL-3'
}
```

At a glance it's pretty clear that `jsonText` contains properties which `rowContent` does not contain.  So when you attempt to read those properties from `rowContent` they will be `undefined`.  And trying to invoke `.replace` on `undefined` will fail.

It's not really clear what this code is *trying* to do.  But the one thing that is clear is that you can't use a property that doesn't exist.  Perhaps you could check for the property before trying to use it?  For example:

```
for (const header of Object.keys(jsonText)) {
  if (rowContent[header] !== undefined) {
    const text = jsonText[header].replace(/s+/gm, '');
    const content = rowContent[header].replace(/s+/gm, '');
    expect(text).toStrictEqual(expect.stringContaining(content));
  }
}
```

Or perhaps you didn't intend to read from `rowObject` in the first place and this is a typo?  Or perhaps these objects *should* be the same structure and there's a mistake somewhere else in the code?  It's impossible to know given the content of the question.  But the source of the error itself is simple, you can't use an object property that doesn't exist.

Comment: your code is works :D, thank you David, have good day!!!

Answer (score 1):

This means that `rowContent[header]` is undefined.

Inspect rowContent - e.g. by placing a `console.log(rowContent);` after `const rowContent = ....`  this should give you some clues and maybe log the `header` value inside the for loop.

Comment: console.log(rowContent[header]) returns  some unexpected undefined value.         runtime value of console.log(rowContent):"{
      Time: '2021-07-10 03:42:01.000 (1 month ago)',
      'Node name': 'sapc17'
    }"      .       run time value of console.log(rowContent[header]) :"sapc17". "2021-07-10 03:42:01.000 (1 month ago).  "undefined". "undefined""